# Javascript redirect strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I am trying to do a JavaScript redirect inside an event handler. The event handler receives the message from child and when I receives the message I want to do a simple JS redirect.

I have tried the following:

1. `window.location.href = url;`
2. `window.location = url;`
3. `window.location.replace(url);`
4. `$(location).attr('href',url);`

But none of the above did the redirecting. Then I put an `alert` just before the redirect code line. I got the `alert` and when I click on it, the redirect worked.

So with alert it works, but when I remove the alert it is not redirecting.

Can you guys help me to figure this out? Any aspects that I should look at? Any clues?

### Edit

This is the code block I used to send message to parent (which is inside an angular controller)

```
$scope.$watch(
    function () { return vm.redirect; },
    function () {
        window.parent.postMessage({action: 'redirect', value:vm.redirect_url}, "*");
    }
);
```

And here is the code that I used to catch the message and do redirect.

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
    switch( e.data.action ){
        case 'redirect':
            var url = e.data.value;
            //alert("**");
            window.location.href = url;
            //window.location = url;
            //window.location.replace(url);
            //$(location).attr('href',url);
            console.log("INSIDE REDIRECT: ("+url+")");
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}, false);
```

Hope this satisfies the comments!

Comment: can you show full javascript code?

Comment: Show the whole code in a context, one line of code doesn't give any information.

Comment: Your browser is blocking the redirect. Please select allow on the upper right side of menu bar

Comment: Something is happening in the background (perhaps the HTML is finishing loading) that is causing the change to `window.location` to be ignored.  Because you're doing the `alert` and javascript is blocking whatever it is has time to complete, making the redirect possible.  This is a guess.  It's not possible to be definitive without an [mcve].  As-is, this question is off topic: unclear

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited my question as per your comments!

Comment: Is the url complete with the `http://`

Comment: Yes @dannyliu. It redirects when I have the alert before the code. Its not working only when alert is not there!

Comment: so setTimeout may be helpful ? @masterFly

Comment: Hi @dannyliu, You were exactly RIGHT!!! I just found it and tried it + saw your comment! THANK YOU!!! Please add this as an answer if you don't mind!

Comment: OK.  So glad that you fix the problem.@masterFly

Comment: @masterFly as a matter of interest, could you try `window.location.href = url,true;` instead please?

Comment: @Tibrogargan, it did not make any difference.

Comment: @dannyliu, Even though it works, for the mobile its still not re directing.

Comment: @masterFly how about setting the time longer like 100  ms?

Comment: @dannyliu, Yep It worked. But still I cant figure out why it is happening like that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it redirects when having the alert before the code, so I think it may work by using setTimeout as following:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = url;},100);
```